# Screen Capture ala Draw Something

Tags: javascript, python, html, video, screen-capture

I recently spent some time playing a game called Draw Something ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.omgpop.dstfree), [iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/draw-something-free/id488628250?mt=8)). I like the way one player can draw to the screen and the drawing will be re-created for the second player. I want to use something similar to this on my website, but I'm not sure how.

The project I'm working on will use a One-To-Many connection, rather than Draw Something's One-To-One connection. Essentially a user will make a drawing and it should be recreated for anyone who views it.

Is it possible to do this on the web using some combination of HTML5, JS, and Python?

Answer (score 2):

Easily done with `ontouchstart`, `ontouchmove` and `ontouchend`. Example: http://ontouchstart.github.com/

Just track the coordinates of the touch event (or mouse, but use `onmousedown`, `onmousemove` and `onmouseup`) and send it to the server. The server then sends the data to the other clients which draw everything based on the coordinates from the events.

Comment: Sounds good! Could I track the coordinates using an Array? Also, I don't want everything drawn all at once. I want to replicate the process of the image being created, not just the final product.

Comment: Sure, as long as you track all the events and include timing data it can be stored as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library using Raphaeljs http://ianli.com/sketchpad/.  It stores the drawing in a JSON format that you could use to redraw wherever you need it.  I'm not sure how well it would be suited for what you want to do, but it might work.

Comment: The only problem is with this is that the data sent to the viewer should be more like a movie. They will see the process of the image actually being draw as opposed to just being shown the final result.

Comment: @ManiacalScience you wouldn't have to send it at every step.  You could send the JSON whenever they are done.